# What now night mother?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any point at all for doing the last missions for the Dark Brother Hood? The last mission is repeating but does it ever end or is it just a continuous source of gold that you can farm over and over again with ease? To tell the truth I just want it gone from the quest bar because the night mother is continuing to nag me until I do the mission. And even then it irritates me as it becomes the next quest available immediately.

Answer (score 6):

I had limited success with the console command:

```
resetquest DBrecurring
```

On one computer where I used it the quest came back right away. On another it failed, then I got it to work (I think) with careful timing: first I completed the quest, then I entered "resetquest DBrecurring" quickly in the console before it had a chance to repeat. I haven't test extensively, so I can't swear timing was the fix, but that worked for me.

For a less touchy solution, PC users can download a mod from the Skyrim Nexus that disables the quest.

- A number of people have endorsed [dark brotherhood forever moved to misc](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=10194), but it just moves the quest to the Misc category and I wanted it completely gone.
- [Stop The Dark Brotherhood Forever Quest From Returning](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=15567) was uploaded more recently and worked perfectly for me. Note that this just keeps it from recurring once it's completed. To force it to complete you can either fulfill the contract or go into the console and enter: setstage dbrecurring 200

Answer (score 4):

I will never be gone, its another one of those [radiant quests](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Dark_Brotherhood_Forever) that are randomly generated.  And since the quest targets are always created at the start of the quest, you can't get around it by killing every NPC in the game either.

If you are on the PC, however, you can get rid of the quest with this console command:

> resetquest DBrecurring

Comment: Ugh, thanks Its just sort of irritating. I guess the "Beautiful Barbarian" NPC that spawns at the start of some is pretty funny though.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, you CAN "kill" this string of pointless quests. Caution: some spoilers below. Like FeralChimp said five years ago, you can use setstage dbrecurring 200 . This forces it to complete, but then what happens is that the Night Mother calls you again for the NEXT contract (because it only kills the current contract not the entire quest). Over and over. But I thought to myself: can the programmers have made an endless loop? That would be lame since they'd start completely repeating. So I stood in front of the Night Mothers coffin, called up the console (`) and typed setstage dbrecurring 200 and hit Enter. It ended that individual murder/quest and then it went back to asking me to go see the Night Mother. So in the console, I hit the "up" arrow to re-enter setstage dbrecurring 200 and again hit Enter. That would end the part of the quest where I'm talking to the Night Mother and I was again supposed to do the contract.  I entered the same string AGAIN and hit enter and that ended the murder part. Over and over. The point is, every time I ended the conversation with Mother and then ended the contract by doing this, it would put me further down "the list" of contracts. Yes, I did this about 100 times in a row, kind of quick. After some minutes, I realized it was no longer asking me to go see mother. I looked at my quest log and I had thirty four completed quests listed, and NO MORE new ones! Mother was done!  I didn't have to kill one more person or travel all over the map and back, and I was rid of the quest being in my log as well as it FINALLY marked it as complete! :)  Also, I decided to install and play "Destroy the Dark Brotherhood 2" (by yuredew - http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/73582/) and that gave me "closure." It's a great mod with some great and fun quests (you better be pretty powerful or have several companions for it) and by the end I got to kill the whole lot of 'em!  Sure, it was a little funky in that I had Cicero in my party and I had already opened up the Dawnstar Dark Brotherhood sanctuary since I had joined them, so I ended up with a second Cicero (who fought "my" Cicero in a hard core fight until I finally stepped in and killed the 2nd Cicero); and it meant I had an entrance to the mod's sanctuary left with all the dead bodies and mass destruction, AND "my" cleaned up sanctuary with Nazir in it, alive and well, but it meant I had been able to stop the madness and the murders and also destroyed the entire brotherhood and Mother and all its nasty villains except Nazir. This was my best option as I chose to start playing this thread at first but later regretted it but couldn't make it stop.  I released Cicero from my party and just let him go back to his sanctuary and cleaning and oiling Mother's dead carcass. It might make a bit more sense if you already have him as a follower to let him go before playing this mod. Good luck!

Comment: You're repeating what was already said, but with a lot more noise.